# Easy Way To Retrofit Half-SASS, Half-CSS to SASS?

Tags: css, sass

I took on a project where the CSS was created via SASS. At the time I wasn't familiar with SASS and began manually updating the last output file. My manager has learned that I haven't been using SASS and is insisting that I change everything I've done (lots of additions and tweaks) into SASS and begin using that again with the project.

Is there any tool that can help me do this? I was thinking maybe generate the last file and look at the difference between that and my currently-edited file and try to add those rules to the SASS file, but I don't know of any tool that will take two files and show you the differences.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to identify how the css file you were working on is. Note that all the comments on sass done via `//` are ignored of output in nested mode. And if the css file you got is in production mode, all the comments are stripped and the css file is minified, which is bad for a conversion.

What I advise is that you backup the css file you're working with; then run `sass watch` into the directory that has the `config.rb`, which will regenerate the css file based on the original sass project.

After that, grab the two files and use a [Diff Tool](http://www.google.com.mx/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=diff%20tool), if you don't want to use a difftool locally you can always create a public GitHub repository and place the original css file, and then commit the new one, to view the differences.

Once you do this, you should go into the files baseed on the compiled selectors, and add the missing attributes.

With that you're pretty much done, in a way that you can keep the comments and original intended structure.

Answer (score 2):

Run `sass-convert` on the CSS file to produce an equivalent SASS file. Then diff the SASS file you created with the original SASS file.

Also, see if there's a way to put a big "AUTOGENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT" banner at the top of generated CSS files :)

Comment: sass-convert comes with sass when you install it and allows you to convert from css to sass or scss. Read more in their 
[documentation](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/#id2).  
I would say keep the original css and use the diff command like @kuroir says.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally just convert the CSS into SASS using css2sass or the command line, learn the SASS syntax, and start trimming down the code by hand (turning oft-repeated styles and such into mixins and extends). It will take some manual labor to go through all the code, but it will be much better for it and work with the existing.

Answer (score 0):

if you run `sass style.scss` it will convert it back to css for you and output the results in the console (prompt) - you can copy and paste from there

run sass --help for info on how to make it write to a file

Answer (score 0):

http://css2sass.heroku.com/

then switch to the scss syntax. it is much better.